# Error Relation does not exist when dll-auto = create

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

My `Entity` class:

```java
package entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "selectAll", query = "from Drug")
public class Drug {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Long price;

    private LocalDate mfd;
    private LocalDate exp;

    public Drug() {
    }

    public Drug(String name, Long price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public LocalDate getMfd() {
        return mfd;
    }

    public void setMfd(LocalDate manufactured) {
        this.mfd = manufactured;
    }

    public LocalDate getExp() {
        return exp;
    }

    public void setExp(LocalDate exp) {
        this.exp = exp;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Drug{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                ", mfd=" + mfd +
                ", exp=" + exp +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My `Config` class:

```java
package config;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"service","entities","dao"})

public class Config {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("123");

        return dataSource;
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", "create");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.generate-ddl","true");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.database-platform","postgres");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("entities");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager (SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

}
```

My application:

```java
package ir.training.ds;

import config.Config;
import entities.Drug;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import service.DrugService;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DsApplication.class, args);



        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        DrugService drugService = applicationContext.getBean(DrugService.class);

        Drug drug = new Drug("aaa",111l);
        drug.setMfd(LocalDate.now());
        drug.setExp(LocalDate.of(2022,01,02));
        drugService.add(drug);

    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1366)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at dao.DrugDaoImpl.insert(DrugDaoImpl.java:32)
    at service.DrugServiceImpl.add(DrugServiceImpl.java:33)
    at ir.training.ds.DsApplication.main(DsApplication.java:29)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3297)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3824)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "drug" does not exist
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 22 more
```

In XML config, everything works well; but in annotation config, I have this error! What is my mistake?

In annotation config, if table of drug already exists, my app works correctly, but it can not create the table itself!

I have not been able to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", "create");
```

Use:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
```